# How do I add anchor href in data-marquee

Tags: css, marquee

So, I have the snippet below and I'd like to add an anchor link to it. Unfortunately, there is no information on how to.
So, how do I add a link inside a data-marquee attribute?

`<div class="marquee marquee-speed-normal" 
    data-marquee="Some text **I want to have a link in here** Some text">
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this...

An Anchor can in most cases be placed like this. There are loads of info out there with very little effort on finding them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML marquee Tag</title>
</head>

<body>
    <marquee direction="right" scrolldelay="300">
        <a href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquees.htm">This link will take you to a page with what you need to know</a>
    </marquee>
    <marquee direction="right" scrolldelay="300">
        <a href="https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0">And this is why you should try not to use it.</a>
    </marquee>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The marquee you referring is obsolete. I prefer the one I posted in my question as it works better for me. Unfortunately, there is no enough information on the internet.

Comment: I see what you mean there. From what i understand is that you can make the marquee a link but it does't work if you add the anchor into data-marquee.

The most detailed source is the GitHub (https://github.com/muchweb/html5-marquee)

Answer (score 0):

Try this then. From what i've seen, the easiest way was to turn the entire marquee into a link like below. The reason seems to be that data-marquee prints the data and won't represent anything else.

It would be great cool to see if there is another way other than that to display a link within the marquee.

```
<a href="#1">
    <h1 class="marquee marquee-direction-alternate" data-marquee="HTML5 marquee"></h1>
</a>
```

Comment: What I want is to have a href link inside data-marquee attribute along with the text.
Example: data-marquee="text+link+text"
I don't want the whole content of the attribute to become a link.

Comment: I see that you've asked that on the GitHub page as well. Please post your answer when you figure it out. It would be interesting to see how. Good luck :-)

Comment: There are other commented ages ago and as of yet they didn't receive any answers...

Comment: If i might ask out of interest, why are you trying to specifically use that?

Comment: Because, I like to have everything up to date. On there hand, I don't know for how long browsers will keep supporting an obsolete element.

Comment: I agree. Using <marquee> is probably not a good idea. I prefer CSS styling in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't come right, I also found this very useful. Here i have done the same with CSS. This is still widely supported.

```
*/The behavior is determined with CSS*/
<style>
        .scroll-slow {
            height: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background: yellow;
            color: orange;
            border: 1px solid orange;
        }

        .scroll-slow p {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            /* Starting position */
            -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
            /* Apply animation to this element */
            -moz-animation: scroll-slow 25s linear infinite;
            -webkit-animation: scroll-slow 25s linear infinite;
            animation: scroll-slow 25s linear infinite;
        }
        /* Move it (define the animation) */

        @-moz-keyframes scroll-slow {
            0% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes scroll-slow {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }

        @keyframes scroll-slow {
            0% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
                /* Browser bug fix */
                -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                /* Browser bug fix */
                transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
                /* Browser bug fix */
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
                /* Browser bug fix */
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
    </style>

*/ And then the anchor is done as follows */
    <div class="scroll-slow">
          <p><a href="#1">This is my link</a></p>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Jim, a long shot

I Is this what you want to do?.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Marquee Plugin Example</title>

    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>

    <style>
        .marquee {
            width: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background: #ccc;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="marquee"><a href="#1">This is my link</a></div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script> </body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
$(".marquee").marquee({
  //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
  duration: 5000,
  //gap in pixels between the tickers
  gap: 50,
  //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
  delayBeforeStart: 0,
  //'left' or 'right'
  direction: "left",
  //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
  duplicated: true
});
```